# Database not visible in DDMS folder when real device used instead of emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, ddms

I am creating a sample application which will create a database, Inserts data and finally displays it in a spinner.

For testing I am using my android phone instead of Emulator (As I am fedup with its slow response).

My problem is application running succesfully but spinner is not displaying any result also I am unable to view any folder structure under DDMS->data.

I am confused whether database created or not, Please suggest me how to view the database if we use real device instead of emulatpor

Comment: do you have the permissions?

Comment: Use `adb root` command from terminal and do the same steps as you use to see databases into emulator

Comment: i guess you will need root access. i am not sure though. but om emulator you should see the database

Comment: root access for device is required bro.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply.. Will provide root access and try to view

Answer (score 5):

You must start you emulator, browse the emulator files in the DDMS view then select File explorer then  go to data > data > com.your.package > databases > your_database_name and a new tab will appear with your data! It won't work on a real device.

You can even pull/export the database and analyse it more effectively with [SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

You can't get SQLite databse file from an Android real device if it is not rooted. Because to access the data folder of your application you have to provide the permission for it.

But you can run your application in an android emulator and following is the way:

1. From DDMS, in Devices menu select your emulator.
2. You can see data folder in File Explorer.

   Path is: data->data->Application Package Name->Databases->Database Name

Comment: Thanks Manali for your reply.. Will try as adviced.

Comment: I have rooted my device but still cannot access SQLite db ! Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259190/how-to-view-sqlite-database-in-android-phone/24259250#24259250)

Answer (score -1):

U just goto File Explorer
Windows>show view>File explorer>data>package>database name to see your database
in emulator

Comment: Thanks for Such a quick response.. Will try and mark your reply as answered.

Comment: @siva-if your database is not shows then check in Manifest file u give the permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE