# Sqlite database is not visible in sdcard when I use windows file manager

Tags: android, sqlite, file-manager

I changed the default directory of my database to the sdcard and I want to acccess this database and see its data using sqlitebrowser ,However I can see this database from my android file manager but when I am using windows file manager I cannot see the file of database in my sdcard , I thing it is about permission issues , But How can I solve that  ?

my database is here

```
public static String SDCard =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    + File.separator ;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {


        super(context, SDCard +DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        transactionManager = new TransactionManager(getConnectionSource());
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database not visible in DDMS folder when real device used instead of emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437347/database-not-visible-in-ddms-folder-when-real-device-used-instead-of-emulator)

Comment: Do you mean that when you connect your phone to PC and open SDCard , you can't see the database?

Comment: it is a different question because I changed the default location to the sdcard

Comment: In Windows explorer, make sure you have "Show hidden files and folders" enabled.

Comment: How are you mounting the card on Windows? USB mass storage or MTP?

Comment: Windows explorer, make sure you have "Show hidden files and folders" enabled , didn't work for me :(

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush ok, sorry

Comment: @deadfish It's not a duplicate as user has already changed the database location from default to SD-Card so as SD-card is getting created onto SD-card, he/she must be able to see/view it.

Comment: @PareshMayani - a lot changed since fist version of this topic, so it might be not duplicate now

Comment: @deadfish agree but I just posted a comment with the aim to prevent the duplicate votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Android phones have their internal memory split into two blocks.

One is used for the internal or / folder. The other part of the internal memory is returned by getExternalStorageDirectory(). This is still internal memory from user and/or PC side. But for Android it is external memory.

So probably you are looking in the wrong folder.

For example in my Samsung S4 I have:

```
  /
  /storage/emulated/0
  /storage/extSdCard
```

"/storage/emulated/0" is returned from getExternalStorageDirectory(), while "/storage/extSdCard" is my external SD card.

Comment: How could I edit the code to put the file on the top of my sdcard

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush, That sir, is a very good question. Since all devices I have seen use a different path to mount the SdCard, you can only ask the user for the path. (And the user will probably not know).

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush, I found this answer to be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871043/11492

Answer (score 0):

### Physical Device

You need to have a phone with **root access** in order to browse the data folder (`data/data/your.app.package.name`) on an Android phone which means either you have a developer device or you've *rooted* your device.

(You also need to be running ADB in root mode and this can be achieved on the commandline using `adb root`)

If your phone does not have root access, you will not be able to gain access to the database.

The database will have `rw-rw----` as the permission as default. In order to access the database you should change the permission level using `chmod` on *nix systems or through the folder permission dialogs in Windows (**right click the folder and set permissions to everyone**)

### Emulated Device

See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002252/717778). You can access the database using the DDMS perspective

Comment: The user clearly states that database is in SDCard not in data thus root access is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a device in MTP mode has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282) where the MTP database isn't updated correctly and newly created objects are not visible to the client computer.

As a workaround, you can use `MediaScannerConnection` `scanFile()` to force refresh the database after creating your directories/files.