# How to view sqlite database using real device

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've been searching this for quite a long time and I found the following steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259250/5256621

> 1.Connect your device and launch the application in debug mode.
>
> 2.Copy the database file from your application folder to your sd card:
>   execute:
>
> ./adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name cat
>   /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/filename.sqlite >
>   /sdcard/filename.sqlite"
>
> 3. Pull the database files to your machine: execute:
>
> ./adb pull /sdcard/ execute: ./adb
>
> 4. Install Firefox SQLLite Manager:
>      https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
>
> 5.Open Firefox SQLLite Manager and open your database file from step 3
>   above.

Where can I find my database file ? The data file shows empty although I have rooted my device. I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I really do not know how to access SQLite using real device.

Some said that database can be accessed once the device is rooted but not works for me. [How do I view the SQLite database on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user Root Explore,before this,you must root your device and user root permission to run the app ,then open and find data folder and open the folder then continue find data folder and open ,you will find the app files in this device,find your packagename and you can find the db,you can use copy the db to sdcard

Comment: I have rooted my device but the data folder still empty

Comment: i use other app to browse and i find empty folder,you can try this app

Comment: the app can dowmload anywhere,find your db and copy to sdcard.then you can open you sd card to browse the db.

Comment: But where to find my db?

Comment: in you app folder ,there is nothing ? i use my phone and can find any app's config contain db lib cache sharepreference...

Comment: I cannot search my data package in app folder

Comment: how do you find your app data package ? app data save at /data/data/your packagename

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94401/discussion-between-hoo-and-ljl5241861).

Comment: I have find my db and table as well. How to see the content?

Comment: you can use software to open the db,i usually use sqlite expert to open the db

Comment: it is a windows software not  a apk,you can search with google :),you need copy the db into your complter

Comment: Can copy the db to `SQLite Manager`?

Comment: Which app should I use to see  inserted image from android studio?